# Remove Garbage Disposal romex or cap?

Tags: electrical, garbage-disposal

My garbage disposal is busted and my wife wanted to be rid of it anyways.  It's hard-wired and, after some trial and error, I found it is on the same circuit as a GFCI above the sink.  (Not the same circuit as the dishwasher).

AFAIK I have two options here regarding the GD romex:

1) Use wire nuts, electrical tape, and a blank electrical box to cap the live wires.  Probably nail it into the kitchen cabinet.  That would allow a future homeowner to wire a new GD if they wanted.

2) Pull the GFCI outlet and see if the GD romex is just extending off the GFCI.  If so, remove and pull the romex completely out.

Advice?  I'm a relatively novice DIYer, I've capped a few blank boxes but I don't want to make my house's wiring even more funhouse than it is.

Comment: Do you have the ability to wire to a new outlet under the sink (if your local laws permit)? That way a new disposal (with a cord) could be later installed with no wiring at all.

Comment: Don't remove the wire.  Its going to be stapled inside the wall so you can't just pull it out.

Comment: @DragonYen  Maybe, but this is a 100-year-old house and the wiring is not great to start with.  And since I don't want a GD to begin with, not eager to put a ton of money into a new installed outlet

Answer (score 1):

Your best and safest path forward would be to purchase an old work box and a blank cover. Instal the old work box in the wall with the wiring inside the box. 
Nailing a box to the cabinet would violate code in many locations as the romex must be protected under the sink.

Old work boxes are inexpensive and made for jobs like this. With the wires safely capped inside the covered box is the least expensive way to do this and the circuit can be used in the future if needed.

Comment: An old work box is what I meant by a "blank box."  Question though, should I try to secure the box to the top of the undersink cabinet with a couple nails?  I would like to keep the box off the floor of the cabinet where water, cleaning chemicals, etc could get to it...  ETA: the romex right now is just coming through a small hole in the lathe&plaster, so I really can't stuff the old work box in it without removing some of the wall.

Comment: Having the romex exit the wall without conduit is a code violation. Making the hole large enough for the old work box to fit in the hole then tighten the wings so it will be secure. Old work boxes some times called remodel boxes usually have 2 wings that are inside the wall and support the box in place. Prior to putting the box in the wall the wires are fed through one of the openings to be contained in the box and the box put in the wall and the wings tightened. Then you could add the blank cover.